# utf8_(en|de)code removed from php7?

Tags: php, utf-8, mbstring

I recently switched to PHP 7 on my development server, which has worked just fine - until now.

Since I updated to `PHP 7.0.3-10+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` (earlier today), the `utf8_decode` and `utf8_encode` functions are no longer accessible. They were, however, in previous versions of PHP7. When called, a fatal error is raised.

I read that these functions are provided by the `mbstring` extension, which I checked with `var_dump(extension_loaded('mbstring'));` is loaded.

How can I get the above functions to work again?

Comment: `mbstring` does not provide this function. Oddly enough, it's listed in [XML Parser Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php). Maybe you'd like to elaborate a bit on the error message? Quick testing on my (custom) PHP7 shows it "still" works...

Comment: The full error message is `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function utf8_encode() in ...`. I managed to replace the encode function with `mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8')`, but I still want to know what causes the error.

Comment: I needed the function to convert strings I got from LDAP. What else can I tell about the error message?

Comment: Is this the *same* package? That is, did 7.0.3-9 not produce this error? If so, you might want to consider filing a bug report with `deb.sury.org`.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I don't remember which version the server ran before, but the error did definitely not occur before the update to 7.0.3-10. I will do some research about the recent changes of PHP7. Thanks for bringing me on track!

Comment: If you run `php -m` does it list `xml`? You probably need to install some package like `php7-xml`.

Comment: Nailed it, thank you! No `xml` extension -> installed it -> problem solved. Feel free to write this as an answer so I can officially accept it.

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8')` only does the same thing as `utf8_encode($value)` if your `default_charset` (PHP 5.6+) or `mbstring.internal_encoding` (PHP 5.5 or earlier) is set to "ISO-8859-1". Otherwise you'll want to explicitly set the from encoding with `mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm back to `utf8_encode` anyways.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just install `php7.0-xml` package. Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Edit: **Restart apache2** to load the new package.

Comment: Restarting apache should be in bold. But thank you, this worked for me.

Comment: Just to note, `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` have been moved into ext/standard as of 7.2, so they will be always available from that point on (ext/standard is always available).

Comment: The package has changed names on apt, you should use

`sudo apt-get install php-xml`

Comment: same solution works if you are using `nginx` with `php-fpm`, except of course, you need to restart `nginx`

Comment: No,  u need to restart php-fpm the web server has nothing to do with reloading php if you run it as fast-cgi.

Comment: Is it me or ppa:ondrej/php doesnt have php7.0-xml?

Answer (score 12):

On Ubuntu, you got the following message during the upgrade of PHP7:

```
php7.0 (7.0.3-6) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Several extensions have been split into separate extension packages:
   - php-dba - Database (dbm-style) Abstraction Layer
   - php-mbstring - Multibyte String
   - php-soap - SOAP
   - php-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, XMLReader and XMLWriter
   - php-zip - Zip
  * The new packages are not installed automatically, so you will need to
    install them by hand, if you use the functions in those modules.
  * Most modules that have been builtin before are now included in
    php7.0-common package and they are enabled by default for your
    convenience.  You can disable unneede modules via phpdismod tool.

 -- Ondřej Surý <ondrej@debian.org>  Mon, 22 Feb 2016 12:37:09 +0100
```

so it's one of those packages that's causing the problem. In this case, it's `php-xml`.

Note the

> The new packages are not installed automatically

You can fix that by

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

Comment: In case anyone encounters mb_regex_encoding not found in php7.0, install php-mbstring works for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on CentOS, following command should work:

```
yum install php-xml
```

Comment: ...same for Fedora 24

Answer (score 4):

As the top voted answer did not work for me i found yet another package for php7 which (obvious by its name) fixed it for me

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

Comment: Simply using `sudo apt install php-mbstring` will do the trick as well - without version hassles.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with php 5.6, try:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

The utf8_decode and utf8_encode functions are accessible in php 7:

[function.utf8-encode - manual - php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

This is because the php-xml package is missing in your php installation.

If your server is running Mandrake, enter "urpmi php-xml".

If your server is running EASYPHP on Windows, click on the EASYPHP logo to activate the php-xml module.

On debian or ubuntu try :

```
apt-get install php7.0-xmlrpc
```

Comment: `php7.0-xmlrpc` or `php7.0-xml`, or both?

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem and for me,

```
sudo apt-get install php-patchwork-utf8
```

and restarting the apache2 server solved the problem (on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).