# utf8_encode() and curl_init() not working on PHP7

Tags: php, nginx, php-7

I've just made the transition to Ubuntu from Windows, and I've set up a fresh install of nginx, mysql, php7.0-fpm (including the Opcache/ApcCache) and cloned a project from git (Yii2 project).

This repository worked on windows, but it now seems some of the built-in functions are no longer working. I've checked the docs, and it does not seem like any of the functions are deprecated.

This is the errors i've found so far, code-snippets and their corresponding error messages:

**curl_init()**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getSlackPayloadUrl());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

> Call to undefined function backend\components\curl_init()

**utf8_encode()**

```
$data = 'payload=' . json_encode(array_map("utf8_encode", [
            'channel'       =>  $channel,
            'text'          =>  $message,
        ]));
```

> array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'utf8_encode' not found or invalid function name

And for thoroughness, the nginx config:

**nginx config**

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name project.dev;
    root        /var/www/project/backend/web;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /var/www/project/log/access.log;
    error_log   /var/www/project/log/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

If there is any other information that is relevant, add a comment and I'll update.

Comment: I'll check that, but the utf8_encode() function is a php standard, right?

Comment: Well, http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php, yeah. It did work on windows.

Comment: Yeah,we solved the curl bit - just installed the package. But its really this built-in function that I'm stuck at.

Comment: Solved it, thanks for your help

Comment: Actually your solution lies here:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701730/utf8-endecode-removed-from-php7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per our discussion discussion , below solution comes:-

1.Need to install `CURL` on your system by the command :-

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

2.Regarding second error i got this link:- [utf8_(en|de)code removed from php7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701730/utf8-endecode-removed-from-php7)

It states that `utf8_encode/decode` is function related to `php xml extension` which you have to install your system by below command:-

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

***Important Note:-*** after install of these library packages ***restart*** your ***server*** so that ***changes will reflect***. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`utf8_encode()` is a function under the `php xml extension`, and `curl` of-course under the `curl extension`.

Solved by

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Comment: I added that link in my comment which shows the second part of your answer is missed. BTW +10