# string using \u as that codepoint's UTF-8 representation in php

Tags: php, utf-8

In [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) stated that

> \u{[0-9A-Fa-f]+}  the sequence of characters matching the regular
>   expression is a Unicode codepoint, which will be output to the string
>   as that codepoint's UTF-8 representation (added in PHP 7.0.0)

```
echo "\101";  //Output A

echo "\x41";  // Output A

echo "\u0041"; //But its now working. output same as \u0041
```

i am unable to understand `\u`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read through [this well explaining blog post](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) of the current CEO of stackoverflow (funny coincidence).

Basically to quote the relevant part (about the "u"):

> The U+ means “Unicode” and the numbers are hexadecimal. U+0639 is the Arabic letter Ain. The English letter A would be U+0041.

**UPDATE**

Your problem seems actually connected to a missing implementation between PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.2 -> [Read this SO-Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902105/8683679)

Comment: echo "\u+0041" does not work. give same output \u+0041

Comment: yep. Just recognized. What's your PHP-Version?

Comment: PHP version 7.1

Comment: just recognized, you spared the `+` at the end of the sequence. Does it work, when you add it?

Comment: Ah... found it in [this SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902105/8683679). It has nothing to do with a wrong syntax but with missing utf8-functions in PHP in betwee 7.0.x and 7.2.0