# PHP 7 cannot run utf8 functions

Tags: php

I am hitting the same problem as reported here: [utf8_(en|de)code removed from php7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701730/utf8-endecode-removed-from-php7) but nothing from any of the ideas have worked.

I've just run:

`apt-get upgrade`
followed by `apt-get install php7.0-xmlrpc php7.0-xml` and Ubuntu tells me *both `is already the newest version`.

If I run my simple test script:

`echo function_exists('utf8_encode') ? 'Good' : 'Bad';`

(Equally if I replace utf8_encode with simplexml_load_file this too returns Bad)

I am constantly seeing "Bad". I'm *not running from apache* (although it is installed on the server) I am running direct from the command line.

I've also done a reboot and still no progress. PHP Version reports:

`7.1.13-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1`

Which is wierd considering I thought this function was still in at this point?

So my question is how can I get utf8_encode/decode working??

Comment: Can you update your question to include your actual issue? Linking to another post and say: "I have the same problem" isn't good enough. If that post would, for what ever reason, get deleted, this question wouldn't make any sense for future visitors.

Comment: You should also check your php.ini that XML extension is actually loaded. You can create info.php file with `<?php phpinfo();` content and open it to see if the XML is loaded at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are installing the wrong version of the xml extension: You seem to be installing the version for php 7.0 and you are using php 7.1.

Try looking for - and installing - `php7.1-xmlrpc` and `php7.1-xml`.

Comment: Massive thanks `apt-get install php7.1-xml` fixed it - I will make this the answer and good spot. I had assumed the 7.0 worked for all 7 when it clearly didnt.

Answer (score 0):

Try [installing the mbstring extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42875896/6352706).

Unicode features were moved into the [mbstring extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). Check out the documentation for all of the available functions there.

Comment: I get `php7.0-mbstring is already the newest version (7.0.27-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1).` :(

Comment: Try @jeroen's answer. Otherwise, you should be able to use the functions that are included in `mbstring` for all your unicode needs.