# How to debug the HTTP ERROR 500 with apache and php?

Tags: php, apache, rest, debian, http-error

I have a Rest API that works on my local machine. But when uploading it to the server I get some errors.

I installed Apache, PHP and the php-cli package.

```
$ sudo apt install apache2
$ sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php 
$ sudo apt install php-cli
```

I enabled the Apache module and mod_rewrite in Apache

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.0
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I also verified that mod_rewrite is enabled with:

```
$ ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | grep rewrite
```

And I tested that PHP worked on the web server using SSH

```
$ sudo wget http://localhost/info.php
```

---

My directory v0 contains index.php and .htaccess

When making any request with Postman I get the following errors:

- The requested URL /APIs/cluvi/v0/employees  was not found on this server
- Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at < EXTERNAL-IP > Port 80

When entering from the browser I get the following error:

- HTTP ERROR 500

Then I have some observations:

1. When you delete the .htaccess file the error persists.
2. **When deleting the file index.php the error disappears** when I enter the directory v0 from the browser because the contents of the directory are displayed.

---

I also read that it could be a permissions issue. My permissions set to folders and files are:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data your_username
$ sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html 
$ sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```

I have deployed APIs with LAMP and I had no problems. But maybe by installing Apache and PHP separately I'm not considering something that I do not realize. Or I have some error in the index.php code that I am not seeing and I would like to know how to debug this HTTP status.

---

## SOLUTION

### /var/log/apache2/error_log

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(webpresentation/views/JsonView.php): failed to open stream: No such file or direct$
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'webpresentation/views/JsonView.php' (include_path=$
```

**Solution:**
In the URL of the request had a segment of more, which did not exist in the directory structure of the server project.
Therefore, the solution was to compare the URL with the directory structure and match them.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function utf8_encode() in /var/www/html/APIs/cluvi/app-cl$
```

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902105/5279996): `$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml && sudo systemctl restart apache2`

And finally I had the following errors:

- PHP Warning:  require_once ...
- PHP Fatal error:  require_once()

Which **I solved** keeping the require_once () that I had in the application deployed locally.

> Finally, my main solution was the use of the file `/var/log/apache2/error_log` and the installation of `php7.0-xml` to avoid the HTTP ERROR 500.

Thank you

Comment: If the error is 500, then there should be something on the error log of php

Comment: You should read the php error logs. I would recommend to create an docker development environment that matches the stack of your server, it will prevent problems like this in the future!

Comment: http://35.243.140.230/info.php

Comment: @RomanoSchoonheim Does LAMP prevent this too? If you have a tutorial to recommend Docker I would read it with pleasure.

Comment: When deleting the file index.php the error disappears when I enter the directory v0 from the browser because the contents of the directory are displayed.... it seems you have fatal error in index,php file

Comment: @RomanoSchoonheim Someone is struggling to find their error logs, and you're suggesting *Docker*!? That sounds like telling someone who's just learning to walk to "try running, you'll go faster". The key advice here is to **read the PHP error logs**.

Comment: @IMSoP I totally agree with you, it was a ridiculous suggestion to use docker to prevent environmental issues. ITDevelopers ignore the docker suggestion, reading the error logs will help you!

Comment: @RomanoSchoonheim It's a reasonable suggestion *for someone at a level where they have a chance of succeeding at it*. Docker is not a simple technology, so someone starting out is just going to have a whole new set of headaches trying to understand it. If the question was "I'm migrating from environment X to environment Y and I get this error because of a difference in server configuration" then "try using Docker to minimise the differences when you migrate" might be a good answer; but my impression is the OP in this case isn't at that stage.

Comment: I solved my error using the php log

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde There was content displayed because I had SetEnv DEVELOPMENT On

Comment: @IMSoP Anyway I have read documentation and displayed Docker images (Jira Unofficial Software) but I wanted to use only what is necessary for this API. And I did not use LAMP because I have the db in another server.